# Dynamic type inside a Linq-to-sql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, reflection, dynamic

I'm trying to refactor a query that currently uses reflection:

```
var dbObjects = from d in collection  
    where d.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(d, null) == id  
    select d;
```

I would like to use dynamic typing to access the property Id on "d" without knowing what type "d" is at compile time.
Something like this:

```
var dbObjects = from (dynamic)d in collection  
    where d.Id == id  
    select d;
```

Is this possible?
... and out of interest, is it faster, or does the dynamic runtime use reflection under the hood?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: How is this linq-to-sql?  The database can't call those reflection methods.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic type uses reflection under the hood so it won't be much faster if any. Because of that I think your Linq-To-Sql expression should work fine. You could check that [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx). It seams that DLR is there only to make your code more readable.